# Using NumPy to generate a sequence of random integers with variable max/min

Tags: python, performance, numpy, random

`numpy.random.uniform` supports array arguments, but `numpy.random.randint` does not:

```
import numpy as np 
two_random_uniforms = np.random.uniform([0, 1], [3, 4])
this_raises_exception = np.random.randint([0, 1], [3, 4])
```

The behavior I want from the second line of code is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for lown, highn in zip([0, 1], [3, 4]):
    result.append(np.random.randint(lown, highn))
```

Is there a way to accomplish the random integer generation with variable max/min without writing a Python loop? The above workaround will be unacceptably slow for the large arrays that my application requires. I can write the loop in Cython, but I'd rather use NumPy if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple thing you could do is just generate floats and round them.

```
def my_randint(low, high):
    return np.floor(np.random.uniform(low, high))
```

It's possible this procedure might tweak the resulting distribution a bit, to make some integers *ever so slightly* more likely than others, but unless you are working with cryptography or some other sensitive application, it probably won't matter.